How to login to confluent platform using confluent cli?
I have installed confluent platform and all the local services are up and running. The problem arises when I try to install a connector, like lets say Postgresql connector by issuing the following command :-
confluent connect plugin install debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:latest
I receive this error:-
`Error: you must log in to Confluent Platform to use this command
Suggestions:
Log in to Confluent Platform with confluent login --url <mds-url>.`
How can I login to Confluent Platform using cli? In the same vein, what is the default MDS url and what are its login credentials?

You shouldn't need to login to anything to install a connector, but you should also try confluent-hub cli instead

Voila Cricketeer buddy that was snappy and neat. Thanks, but do you have any idea about mds url? What is its default port and how can i change its value?

I've never needed, deployed or used the mds server, but the documentation is here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/configure-mds/index.html#configure-the-confluent-platform-mds-long

As directed by OneCricketeer, confluent-hub can be used to accomplish the task.
